# Mudar botão Iniciar sessão para logout

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

*Antes de mais quero avisar que sou um iniciante seja em PHP seja em base de dados e agradeço ajuda porque preciso para entregar um trabalho e estou na deadline*

*Tenho um botão de login e quero que mude para logout quando a sessão for iniciada mas que a condição funcione para múltiplas páginas!*

**Este é o código da minha página login.php para qual o botão de login envia o utilizador quando é clicado!**:

```
        <div class="inner_container">
            <label><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>
            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
            <button class="login_button" name="login" type="submit">Login</button>
                            <a href="registo.php"><button type="button" class="register_btn">Criar conta</button></a>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            @$username=$_POST['username'];
            @$password=$_POST['password'];
            $query = "select * from user where username='$username' and password='$password' ";

            $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if($query_run)
            {
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_run,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                header( "Location: index.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Nome de utilizador ou palavra passe inválida")</script>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Database Error")</script>';
            }
        }
        else
        {
        }
    ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Vc já fez a rotina para apagar a sessão?

Comment: Como assim?????

Comment: Quando a pessoa clicar em deslogar, vc vai apagar a sessão, certo?

Comment: Não tentei fazer isso! Mas vou ter de fazer uma condição para fazer echo ou não?

Comment: Vc quer colocar um botão de logout em todas as páginas, inclusive na de login?

Comment: Eu tenho outras páginas além do index.php que é a página para onde vai o utilizador fazer login corretamente! Eu apenas necessito o botão de login que mude para logout quando o utilizador fizer login corretamente! E quando tiver o botão logout e for pressionado que mude para login já tentei fazer várias condições e não estou chegando lá...

Comment: Pelo que entendi, vc pode colocar o botão logout nas páginas verificando a session com IF, e na página de login redirecionar para a index caso a SESSION esteja cheia

Comment: Já vi pessoal a fazer mas faz uma página em que têm o botão login e o botão logout e quando faz login correto mandar para a página que têm o botão logout e quando tá logout manda para a página que têm login mas eu tenho várias páginas não vou duplicar minhas páginas para fazer isso deve haver uma maneira melhor não?

Comment: Não precisa duplicar nada. Usando IF vc pode verificar se a SESSION está cheia e mostrar um botão ou outro.

Comment: estou tentado o que Leonardo Duarte me está tentado ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque isso nas páginas que gostaria de aparecer os botões, troque o link por um botão.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   echo '<a href="index.php?logout=1">LOGOUT</a>';
}
else
{
   echo '<a href="login.php">LOGIN</a>';
}
```

Na pagina index.php coloque antes de qualquer código

```
$logout = isset($_GET['logout']) ? $_GET['logout'] : "";

if ($logout == 1)
{
unset($_SESSION['username']);
}
```

Nas páginas restritas, poderá inserir esse código abaixo para impedir o acesso caso a variável de sessão esteja nula.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo '
        <div class="erro">
        Não tem permissão para ver o conteúdo desta página.<br>
        <a href="index.php">Voltar</a>
        </div>';
        exit;
}
```

Comment: Sim mas depois o botão de logout queria que me manda-se para a página index.php e passa-se para login visto que o utilizador quis deslogar! Obrigado pela ajuda! Só falta mesmo isso que pedi

Comment: Então no botão logout você direcionada para a index.php?logout=1 e faz uma verificação condiciona na index - if ($_GET['logout'] == 1) unset($_SESSION['username']) assim vai apagar a variável de sessão.

Comment: mas eles não são botões diferentes são echo é só um botão

Comment: amigo, veja o código alterado

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!!!! Voce me salvou

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Voce me ajudou imenso!! Se puder fazer uma explicação eu penso que percebi o que você fez mas penso que não chegaria lá tão depressa porque meus conhecimentos ainda não o permitem!!

Comment: Certo! As variáveis de sessão quando inciadas, elas tem a durabilidade até o fechamento do browser, assim o usuário ativo terá essa variável mesmo mudando de página, ela não perderá o valor. No segundo trecho de código unset que é como expirar essa variável, ela perde o valor. Estou inserindo mais um trecho de código, onde verifica se a variável esta ativa, senão estiver não impede o acesso ao conteúdo da página.

Comment: Mas esse novo código não deixa o utilizador aceder a página sem login feito é isso?

Comment: Sim amigo, neste ultimo código, sem login feito o usuário não consegue entrar na página. Recebe o aviso que não tem permissão e encerra por ali.